# greasemonkey remove span style

Tags: greasemonkey, html

I am trying to create a Greasemonkey script to show text that is in the html, but has the style set to "display:none;". The span has a specific name and can occur any number of times throughout the page.

```
<p><span id="hidden" style="display:none;">Hidden Text</span></p>
```

Any suggestions on how to do this (ideally just removing the "display:none;")

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the hidden element you mentioned "can occur any number of times throughout the page" because `id` should be unique within a page. So I presume what you really meant was `class='hidden'`. Anyway, if the page you are working with is (erroneously) written that way, just replace `'span.hidden'` with `'#hidden'` in the code snippet below.

```
var hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll('span.hidden');
var i = hiddenElements.length;
while(i--) {
    hiddenElements[i].style.display = '';
}
```